# UIFont SIGABRT problem: iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, fonts

I am using the code in my viewDidLoad:

```
[levelLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu-Title" size:20]];
```

To set a font for one of my labels. I also have this font included in the project and in the 'fonts provided by application' section of -info.plist. But when the app loads it freezes and gives me a SIGABRT.

NOTE THAT THIS CODE WORKS ON THE IPHONE SIMULATOR, BUT NOT ON MY 1ST GEN IPOD TOUCH!

Is this the correct way to use custom fonts on iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first gen iPod is running iOS 3.*, which does not support custom fonts to be loaded this way.
The font loading via info.plist is iOS 3.2 (iPad version) and higher.

To use custom font on iOS 3.* use https://github.com/zynga/FontLabel